# Return element of jsonb field with activerecord select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, jsonb

How do I 'select' a value from within a jsonb stored field?

e.g.

```
@model1:
data: {"special_date" => "Wed, 16 Mar 2016 11:20:20 -0700", ....}
@model2:
data: {"special_date" => "Wed, 23 Mar 2016 11:20:20 -0700", ....}
```

I want something like

```
Model.all.select("data -> 'special_date'")
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want a sparse ActiveRecord model instance to hold the data (rather than primitives in an array), you just use `select`:

```
model = Model.select("data -> 'special_date' as special_date'").first
model.id #=> nil
model.special_date = #=> "Wed, 23 Mar 2016 11:20:20 -0700"
```

If you want to fetch the entire record as well as a particular piece of data from within the `jsonb` column, you can chain on `select`:

```
model = Model.select('*').select("data -> 'special_date' as special_date").first
model.id #=> 42
model.special_date #=> "Wed, 23 Mar 2016 11:20:20 -0700"
```

If you don't need the ActiveRecord instance and are okay getting an array back, just use pluck:

```
Model.pluck("data -> 'special_date'")
```

Edit: as of **Rails 6.1** plucking this way will trigger a [ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeReference](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/classes/ActiveRecord/UnknownAttributeReference.html) error so you need to wrap the query with `Arel.sql`:

```
Model.pluck(Arel.sql("data -> 'special_date'"))
```

Comment: I don't want to bring the whole record back. 
I just want to duplicate the functionality of Model.select(:field) but target it at a subcomponent of a jsonb field.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't perfect since it uses pluck rather than select, but

```
Model.pluck("data -> 'special_date'")
```

or if you need more than one column

```
Model.pluck(:id, "data -> 'special_date'")
```

works.